# MySQL and ids edited manually

Tags: mysql

I try to explain my situation through a simple example. I’ve two tables `players` and `goals`. In goals I store goals number for year for each player, which I join in this way:

```
SELECT goals_02, goals_03, goals_04 ecc FROM goals WHERE goals_id = '$player_id';
```

So goals_id and player_id are and must be identical. No problem so far. Due to some problems with my php code, I did some experiments and between a query and the other, ids have gone on to create this situation:

Players Table

```
player_id | player_name
1         | Aaron Mokoena
2         | Abdel El-Saqua
3         | Abdullah Zubromawi
4         | experiment1
5         | test
```

Once solved the problems I started again to add players but not knowing how to start again numbering of ids from where I left off, I manually edited new ids from phpmyadmin... so, I added Abdulrahim Jumaa and changed his id from 6 (automatically assigned by mysql) to 4 and I did the same thing with the goals table.

My problem is that now MySQL doesn’t associate the ids, it seems the player_id and goal_id are different from each other... Perhaps there is a kind of cache where mysql saves the temporary ids?

I cannot figure out what the problem is...

Comment: How are you using your tables to add players? Use select max(player_id) and add one to get the next id available

Comment: @Alfabravo, using max(x)+1 is a very bad idea, use an auto_increment field instead.

Comment: You are right, sir. Using auto_increment or equivalent, getting the id value used for the insert query and then use it in the goals table.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is to change the id to be auto_incrementing and to link the players and the goals.

```
CREATE TABLE players (
  player_id UNSIGNED INTEGER auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  player_name VARCHAR(255)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE goals (
  goal_id UNSIGNED INTEGER auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  player_id UNSIGNED INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_player(player_id) REFERENCES players(player_id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now when you add a new player and a goal to go with it, you can use code like:

```
INSERT INTO players (player_name) VALUES ('Johan Cruijf');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @player_id;
INSERT INTO goals (player_id) VALUES (@player_id);
```

Because the `id` field is auto_incrementing you must **not** specify it when inserting.
Using the build-in MySQL function `last_insert_id()` you can get last generated auto_increment id and use that as input into the next insert statement.

**Comment on your code**
I see you are storing multiple goals in one row. This is bad database design, [what happens if a player scores 13 goals in one game?](http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/archive/edition=4395/preliminaries/preliminary=3863/matches/match=22243/report.html) 
You need to put the `goals` in a separate table from the `games` table and link that to the players and the games.

```
 TABLE goals (
   goal_id UNSIGNED INTEGER auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
   game_id UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
   player_id UNSIGNED INTEGER NOT NULL,
   when DATETIME NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY fk_game(game_id) REFERENCES games(game_id),
   FOREIGN KEY fk_player(player_id) REFERENCES players(player_id)
```

When you want to list all goals in a game, you can do a query like:

```
SELECT go.when, p.name, ga.something
FROM goals go
INNER JOIN players p ON (p.player_id = go.player_id)
INNER JOIN games ga ON (ga.game_id = go.game_id)
WHERE ga.game_id = 1548
```